# How do i inject the original file name (input file) into the defined stream when using siddhi-io-csv extension in siddhi when using WSO2SP

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

In WSO2SP there is a way to use a CSV file to generate events. e.g. the ReceiveEventsFromFile sample. In this sample i can drop a file into a folder and the extension will read the file and produce events.

When i define the input stream i would like to know if there is a way i can get the original file (input file) name as a parameter e.g INPUT_FILE_NAME

Is there functionality to achieve something similar to the below sample.

````
dir.uri='file:/wso2sp-4.3.0/samples/artifacts/ReceiveEventsFromFile/files/new',
action.after.process='move',
tailing='false',
move.after.process='file:/wso2sp-4.3.0/samples/artifacts/ReceiveEventsFromFile/files/consumed',
@map(type='csv', @attributes(ALERT_ID = "1", file = 'file.name')))
@sink(type='log')
define stream BatchFileStream (ALERT_ID string, file string);```

thanks in advance
````

Comment: I don't understand your title: can you fix its grammar?

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of the siddhi CSV mapper the File metedata does not get passed from siddhi-io-file. 
What i had to do is write a custom siddhi-io-file implementation that would pass the metedata to my custom mapper.